# Circuitikz figure squashed/elements not differentiable?

Tags: circuitikz

This is what I have for a small flip-flop circuit (it's incomplete ofc).

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
    \begin{circuitikz}
    % A flip-flop circuit diagram
    (0, 2) \node[american or port]  (myOR1)  {};
    (0, 0) \node[american or port]  (myOR2)  {};
    (2, 2) \node[american not port] (myNOT1) {};
    (2, 0) \node[american not port] (myNOT2) {};

    % Connections
    \draw (myOR1.in 2) -- (myNOT2.out);
    \draw (myOR2.in 1) -- (myNOT1.out);
    \end{circuitikz}
  \caption{A flip-flop circuit.}
\end{figure}
```

This is what it produces:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: You can also put all the nodes (lose the backslash and semicolon) into a single \path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach to possitining of nodes is wrong. Fro them are valid the same rule as in TikZ:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}  

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
    % A flip-flop circuit diagram
    \node[american or port]  at (0, 2) (myOR1)  {};
    \node[american or port]  at (0, 0) (myOR2)  {};
    \node[american not port] at (2, 2) (myNOT1) {};
    \node[american not port] at (2, 0) (myNOT2) {};
    % Connections
    \draw (myOR1.in 2) |- ++ (1.5,-0.5) -- ++ (1,-0.45) -| (myNOT2.out);
    \draw (myOR2.in 1) |- ++ (1.5, 0.5) -- ++ (1, 0.45) -| (myNOT1.out);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Well, also me not finished your flip-flop scheme.